# How to make this expression shorter?

Tags: php

I have to filter array of objects by result of it's method, currently I'm doing it with code

```
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFiltered(): array
    {
        return array_filter($classesToFilter, function(ClassName $class) {
            return $class->filter(); // returns true or false
        });
    }
```

I know that in the same class I can pass callback like

```
    return array_filter($classesToFilter, [$this, "filter"]);
```

But how I can use passed class instead of `$this` in callback?

Comment: Not sure where the variables come from in the method you have, but have you tried `[$class, "filter"]`

Comment: @Nigen Ren, I have object with property that contains array of another objects that have method `filter`, I want to get them filtered by this, method.